# Error in EditorUtility. OpenFilePanel when I build the application

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have implemented a button that when pressed opens the folder selection window, the EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel(), but I just tried to build my application and I get the error "The name 'EditorUtility' does not exist in the current context". From what I saw EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel() only works in unity, when doing the build it doesn't. Is there a way to do the same function as EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel() only in the build?

I've tried to find some alternative but I can't find any way.

Comment: I also use the EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel function and it gives me the same error, does anyone know any alternative for this one as well?

Comment: Every functionality that is from the UnityEditor namespace is not available in the build. So you have to write your own or look for some ready solutions (dunno if there are any, actually)

Comment: You can't use editor functions in a build. Could the file have gotten included in an assembly or something? Also, you can use native C# methods instead e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0):

When accessing anything in the `UnityEditor` namespace, you can't use it in a build outside of the editor. If you really need to have the functionality outside of an `Editor` project, you need to wrap it in a [preprecessor directive for conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation), so it is only available in the editor:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel(...);
#endif
```

Unity defines its own preprocessor directives based on the compiler, platform and other factors and you may add your own in the player settings. For more info, take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).